# How to Log key pressed (key character - lowercase/uppercase) from New Input System in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making Typing Game in unity3d. And have upgraded my old input system to a new input system in unity. If possible I want it on New Input System.

**What I want is:**

If any key is pressed in lowercase then, Log out the lowercase letter inputted from the keyboard.
If any key is pressed in uppercase then, Log out the uppercase letter inputted from the keyboard.

[Example: if a key is pressed then Log a]

[if shift + a => A is pressed then Log A]

In the Old Input System we can get it from `Input.inputString`, but it also doesn't provide upper or lower case letters.